# Error using ==> reshape in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, reshape

I am having an issue when reshaping a cell array:

```
w = size(im,1);                                % width size
h = size(im,2);
d = size(crossfield,3);
for pxRow = 1:h % fixed pixel row
  for pxCol = 1:w % fixed pixel column
    for pxBreadth = 1:d    
      for r = 1:h % row of distant pixel
        for c = 1:w % column of distant pixel
          for z = 1:d
 
            field(c,r,z) = crossfield(c,r,z).*rmatrix(c,r,z);                
 
          end
        end
      end
    b(i) = {field}; % filling a cell array with results. read below
    i = i+1;
    end
  end
end
 
 b = reshape(b, w, h,z);
```

and the error:

> Error using ==> reshape
>
> To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

some other info which may be of use:

```
>> size(im)

ans =

    35    35

>> size(crossfield)

ans =

    35    35     3

>> size(rmatrix)

ans =

    35    35     3
>> size(w)

ans =

     1     1
```

How am I able to reshape b?

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine (no error when I call `reshape`). What is the initial value of `i`? And what do you see when you do `size(b)` after running the loop? I set `i=1;` before the loop, and see `b` as being `1x3675` after running the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your three inner loops have the same effect as doing

```
field = crossfield .* rmatrix;
```

and your three outer loops just set every element of the cell array `b` to the same value. Therefore your code can be simplified to:

```
[w h] = size(im);
d = size(crossfield,3);

b = cell(w,h,d);
b(:,:,:) = {crossfield .* rmatrix};
```

Comment: thanks very much Chris, saves me some computation/typing time.